# Batch loop doesn't loop

Tags: batch-file

Totally new to scripting, but this should work.
Instead I get a single txt file when it should produce up to 10.
thanks in advance!

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
goto :main
:main

setlocal
set /a current=0
set /a total=10

:loop
if !current! lss !total! (
echo stuffstuffstuffstuff.!current! > supercrap.txt
set /a current=!current!1+
        
goto :loop  
)   
endlocal
goto :eof
```

Comment: what are you expecting by `set /a current=!current!1+`?

Comment: Besides the typo in your `SET /A` command, why are you expecting 10 different files?  You do not have any code that would create 10 different files.  The code only ever writes to one file and overwrites it every time. Without knowing all of the technical specifications of what you are doing it seems like you would be better off using a `FOR /L` command instead.

Comment: the current=!current!1+ should enumerate the total till it reached 10.. I thought.. I'm guessing +1 would've done it.

Comment: the set /a.. does it not have to be an integer in order to enumerate/ count up?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of quick examples to assist you:

```batch-file
@Echo Off 
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set /A current=0,total=10
:Loop
If %current% Lss %total% (
    Echo stuffstuffstuffstuff.%current%
    Set /A current+=1
    GoTo loop
)>>"supercrap.txt"
Pause
EndLocal
GoTo :EOF
```

```batch-file
@Echo Off 
SetLocal EnableExtensions
(For /L %%G In (0,1,9) Do Echo stuffstuffstuffstuff.%%G)>"supercrap.txt"
Pause
EndLocal
GoTo :EOF
```

*Please note: delayed expansion is not necessary, so has been omitted.*

Comment: Thanks tons! I'll have a look at this.. I kind of got fed up with batch and moved to powershell.. hoping it would be more streamlined and user friendly. I wanted to get a strong grasp of batch for  a strong learning foundation.. so I will come back to it.